# Palantir Foundry - Can we stop propagating markings in Pipeline Builder?

Tags: palantir-foundry

Can we stop propagating markings in Pipeline Builder?

I'm looking for a way to drop security markings from datasets using the pipeline builder tool in Foundry and I could not figure out if that is possible. Is it possible to drop markings using Pipeline Builder or is it only possible through code repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently only possible in an "unmarking" transform in code repositories, not in Builder.

To note, this is not recommended for datasets as removing markings can unlock datasets to be viewed by any users!

Comment: Not sure about the „not recommended“ part… there are valid reasons to drop markings, e.g. the sensitive data has been aggregated.